# Create Subfolders into multi folder at once time by cmd

Tags: 14.04

Have any way to create subfolders into multi multi folders at once times?  Pls help.

Examples: I have main folder Mango in disk D which contain a lot of folder name as Mango 1, Mango 2, Mango 3, Mango 4 ...etc as path:
D:\ All style numbers\ Mango\ Mango 1
D:\ All style numbers\ Mango\ Mango 2
D:\ All style numbers\ Mango\ Mango 3
D:\ All style numbers\ Mango\ Mango 4

Then I want to create subfolders as " Single photos" in each folder in above. Have any way?.

Examples: Mango/ Mango 1/ Single photos
                    Mango/ Mango 2/ Single photos
                    Mango/ Mango 3/ Single photos
                    Mango/ Mango 4/ Single photos

Answer (score 0):

the solution is as follows in bash while being in `Mango` 
or if you don't want to `cd` into it, simply change line from `for i in *; do` to `for i in path/from/current/path/* do` directory:

```
for i in *; do
  mkdir "$i/Single photos"
done
```